# Solr query or design

Tags: search, solr, elasticsearch

Want to execute queries like :

- category in location1 , location2
- category 1 and category 2 in location1 ,loc2 and  loc3

in our search .

Our challenges :

1. picking right keywords(category and locality) from query entered.
2. its mapping to relevant entity

How should I proceed with this?

We have localities and categories data indexed .

Comment: do you have dog in your solr?

Comment: ajreal.. have you heard about query segmentation.. my question is related to that....

Comment: can you provide some samples .. would help to understand better